# The equality $\chi(G-v)=\chi(G)$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph and $\deg(v)<\chi(G)-1$. By $\deg(v)$ and $\chi(G)$, I mean the degree of vertex $v$ and chromatic number of the graph $G$, respectively. I want to show that $\chi(G-v)=\chi(G)$.

Comment: Is it true that if $G$ is critical, then $\chi(G-v)+1\geq\chi(G)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true vacuously for graphs with one vertex. Suppose then that $G$ has $N$ vertices and assume that $\chi(G-v)=k<\chi(G)=n$. Without loss of generality assume $k=n-1$. Color $G-v$ with $n-1$ colors. Then $v$ is adjacent to vertices with at most $n-2$ different colors since it has degree at most $n-2$. Then we can color $v$ with the $n-1$st color, obtaining a proper coloring of $G$ with fewer than $\chi(G)$ colors, which is a contradiction. Thus $\chi(G-v)=\chi(G)$.

Comment: Trivial complaint: you use $n$ to mean two different things ($|G|$ and $\chi(G)$).

Comment: @angryavian thanks, fixed.

Comment: @MattSamuel Is it true that if $G$ is critical, than $\chi(G-v)+1\geq \chi(G)$? I want to use this to prove.

Comment: @user108209: Of course the inequality $\chi(G-v)+1\ge\chi(G)$ always holds, whether $G$ is critical or not. If $G$ is critical then it becomes an equality.

Comment: @bof Is there a proof for (−)+1≥()? I'm trying to understand it but can't make much intuitive sense of it. A formal proof would be really helpful :)

Comment: @Anthony Color the subgraph properly, then make the new vertex a new color.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality $\chi(G-v)\le\chi(G)$ is clear, so you want to show that
$$\deg(v)+1\lt\chi(G)\implies\chi(G)\le\chi(G-v).$$
This follows immediately from the obvious inequality
$$\chi(G)\le\max\{\chi(G-v),\ \deg(v)+1\}$$
and a simple arithmetical fact:
$$z\lt x\le\max\{y,z\}\implies x\le y.$$